# AWS SES email receiving - 550 mailbox not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I've been trying to set up AWS Simple Email Service as a way to forward emails received to my custom domain on to my Gmail account, without any email hosting service required.

I have set up and verified my custom domain (mycustomdomain.com) as well as verified the email address they'll be forwarded to (myemail@gmail.com) as I'm still in Sandbox mode.

Under Email Receiving -> Rule Sets, I have an active / enabled rule set (forward-to-myemail-gmail) which is enabled, doesn't require TLS and has spam/virus scanning on.

- There are no recipients specified, which I believe should allow this rule to be triggered for ALL recipients under my custom domain.
- I have a single SNS action specified, which is to publish to the SNS topic (sns-forward-to-myemail-gmail) using base64 encoding

I have also set up my SNS topic as above and associated subscription, and have tested sending a notification to this topic manually using the console, so have confirmed it works.

However if I try sending an email to, for example, test@mycustomdomain.com, I get a bounce message back saying:

> **Address not found**
>
> Your message wasn't delivered to test@mycustomdomain.com because the address couldn't be found or is unable to receive email.
>
> The response was:
>
> 550 Mailbox does not exist!

I've also confirmed that the MX records have been set up correctly using mxtoolbox.com, which says the domain records point to feedback-smtp.us-west-2.amazonses.com

Any suggestions for what I'm doing wrong? Many thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok I figured it out... User error, as expected!

I had two MX records, one for the "mail" subdomain and another for "@" meaning the base domain. Both were set to the feedback endpoint, which was the problem. I think I was misunderstanding the two MX records.

The "mail from" configuration that used the SES feedback endpoint needed to be set for the sending subdomain (mail.mycustomdomain.com) while the SES inbound SMTP endpoint should have been used for the receiving domain (@, which means mycustomdomain.com).

Before when I was setting both to the same value I found either get a verified MAIL FROM or received email but not both. Obvious in hindsight! Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Oh and I ended up moving away from forwarding using SNS directly because of the message size limits, which would cause problems for large messages such as with attachments. (I also had to change the payload from base64 to utf8 to get the payload passed through.)

Comment: I ended up using the tutorial at https://medium.com/@ashan.fernando/forwarding-emails-to-your-inbox-using-amazon-ses-2d261d60e417 to use a lambda function to support any sized email. Just keep in mind the Cloud Formation template defaults to Virginia region which may not be what you want.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you. I didn't have the additional MX record setup for the receiving domain. Smooth sailing once that was added.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the answers above. For anyone else working through this, in my case the feedback value (for the mail.xxx.com had to be:

**10 feedback-smtp.[region].amazonses.com**

While the root domain value had to be:

**10 inbound-smtp.[region].amazonaws.com**

note that the feedback domain is AMAZONSES while the inbound domain is AMAZONAWS.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you. It needs to be pointed out!

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else that had some trouble understanding ChrisC's answer, here is more detail on what I needed to do. I setup my domain using Route53, but other domain providers is similar.

### TL;DR

1. Create a custom MAIL FROM domain
2. Add the following records to Route53 or your DNS provider:

| Record name | Type | Value/Route traffic to |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `mail.customdomain.com` | MX | `10 feedback-smtp.[region].amazonaws.com` |
| `customdomain.com` | TXT | `"v=spf1 include:amazonses.com ~all"` |
| `customdomain.com` | MX | `10 inbound-smtp.[region].amazonaws.com` |

### Outbound mail

Go to the Amazon SES AWS console. Under "Configuration," go to "Verified Identities." Under "Custom MAIL FROM domain," provide a custom subdomain (e.g., mail.customdomain.com). Select the option to add the DNS records (an MX record and a TXT record) to Route53 (or just add them manually). See [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/mail-from.html#mail-from-set) in the AWS docs regarding custom MAIL FROM domains.

### Inbound mail

Go to the Route53 AWS console. Under "Hosted zones," click on the domain you want to enable for receiving emails. Add an **MX record** for the base domain (e.g., customdomain.com) with the following value `[priority] inbound-smtp.[region].amazonaws.com`, where `[region]` can be us-east-1, us-west-2, or eu-west 1 (see [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/regions.html#region-endpoints) for full details). **Do NOT use email-smtp.[region].amazonaws.com** for receiving inbound mail. I received a **530 Authentication required** error in the bounce email when attempting to do so.

See [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/receiving-email-mx-record.html) in the AWS docs regarding publishing an MX record for receiving SES email.